# Do edits really need to bump a post in the "active tab"?

Tags: feature-request, editing

A few minutes ago I changed one word in an answer from years ago and I noticed the post (which was closed, in fact) was bumped to the top of the active tab. Is that something that's really desirable and/or is that something the community has any control over?

Comment: It’s pretty built-in as far as I can tell; you might get more clarity on meta.SE

Answer (score 2):

Meta Meta has long discussions of this feature, see [The problem with automatically bumping edited posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178490/the-problem-with-automatically-bumping-edited-posts) and its predecessors, including its use for spotting malicious edits, complaints about "deliberately bumping posts", and requests for "minor edit" marker that would prevent the bumping. Here is Servy's surmise:

> "*If people don't want to look through recently edited posts, and only want to see newly posted content, they can use the "newest" tab rather than the "active" tab. If they're using the "active" tab then it means they specifically want to see questions recently bumped in this manner.*"

Comment: makes sense. might be good if it somehow didnt bump edits by the author under a certain number of characters, but yeah.

Comment: @Timkinsella One concern was that defacing posts by adding /deleting words at strategic places or adding expletives, etc., does not require many characters. Additionally, there is an upside to bumping even minor edits. If someone thought them worth making perhaps the post deserves a chance at getting another look.